# Ubuntu - ZFS on Linux Encrypted Root Pool

Tags: ubuntu, zfs, disk-encryption, plymouth, ubiquity

I am excited that Canonical has added experimental ZoL (ZFS on Linux) support to Ubuntu v20.04 LTS Ubiquity (installer).  Unfortunately, Ubiquity does not yet have the ability to prompt for a ZFS encryption passphrase.

I would like to give a big thank you to Sean Reifschneider for the blog entry "Installing Ubuntu 20.04 with ZFS Native Encryption Enabled":

https://linsomniac.gitlab.io/post/2020-04-09-ubuntu-2004-encrypted-zfs/

I followed this verbatim and simplified the instructions as follows:

```
Boot from "ubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso".

"Install:  Welcome"   ->   button "Try Ubuntu"   ->   

NOTE:  The following is for zpool create of the rpool.

->   button "Show Applications"   ->   shortcut "Terminal"   ->    sudo nano --linenumbers /usr/share/ubiquity/zsys-setup

Scroll down to line 310.  Type "echo MYPASSWORD | " before the text "zpool create -f \".  The finished line should be the following:
        echo MYPASSWORD | zpool create -f \

NOTE:  Line 320 should contain the following text:
                -O sync=disabled \

Insert new lines after line 320 with the following text:
                -O recordsize=1M \
                -O encryption=aes-256-gcm \
                -O keylocation=prompt \
                -O keyformat=passphrase \
->   Ctrl + o   ->   Enter   ->   Ctrl + x

Exit "Terminal".

From the desktop, double-click "Install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS".
```

Please understand that I was performing a first run through test, and I literally made the ZFS encryption passphrase "MYPASSWORD" (without the quotes).  When editing "zsys-setup", I do not recall whether I typed the passphrase using "Caps Lock" or holding down the key "Shift".  Perhaps it does not matter.

After installing Ubuntu on encrypted ZFS root and dealing with the intermittent issue of Plymouth (graphical boot splash screen) not displaying the encryption passphrase prompt, I encounted an unexpected issue.

When the "Caps Lock" is enabled, and I enter the passphrase, it displays the following:

```
Enter passphrase for 'rpool':
<enter MYPASSWORD>
Key load error: Incorrect key provided for 'rpool'.
```

My self-answer will follow momentarily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the "Caps Lock" is not enabled, and I type the passphrase while holding down the key "Shift", the passphrase is accepted, and Ubuntu boots as expected.

Ubuntu v20.04 LTS is running in a QEMU/KVM guest on Linux Mint v19.1, Cinnamon with virt-manager (Virtual Machine Manager).  I am not sure whether this is related, but it seemed worth mentioning.

For comparison, when installing Linux Mint v19.1 with dmcrypt/LUKS, Plymouth passphrase prompts are also an issue, and I typically hide the fancy graphics.  The same workaround worked for Ubuntu v20.04 LTS with ZFS encrypted root:

```
sudo nano --linenumbers /etc/default/grub

Comment the line by changing the line "GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden" to "#GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden".

In the line "GRUB_TIMEOUT" change from "0" to "4".

In the line "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT" change from "quiet splash" to "quiet".

->   Ctrl + o   ->   Enter   ->   Ctrl + x

sudo update-grub

sudo shutdown -r now
```

While it is unlikely that anyone would want to use an all caps passphrase, I hope this helps others following the blog.

2020-05-04 edit:

WARNING:  Using the aforementioned ZFS encrypted rpool process creates a swap partition that is NOT encrypted.  I realize that these are early days and that the feature is marked experimental, but at this time this would be a step backward from a more typical installation using dmcrypt/LUKS and LVM (Logical Volume Manager) which does include encryption for the swap volume.